# Incorrect Request URL given by swagger-ui try it out

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I want to use "try it out" feature given by swagger-ui to test my api. But I get a response with code 500 (Internal Error). But the given curl command executes successfully in Postman.

When I inspect the request using developer tools it shows that Request URL start like "https://app.swaggerhub.com/proxy"

> https://app.swaggerhub.com/proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftest-url%2Fpayment%2Finit

What I actually want is

> https://test-url/payment/init

But the curl command is generated correctly

```
curl -X POST "https://test-url/payment/init" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"...
```

How can I eliminate this "https://app.swaggerhub.com/proxy" part?